# Why is Anonymous Access Required to Host WCF in IIS

Tags: wcf

any insights are helpful

Answer (score 2):

A good explanation can be found on the [.NET Development Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/442be0c8-309e-4000-9311-57189ae7a900):

> [I]t is not true that you have to
>   enable anonymous in order to host WCF
>   in IIS. There are some restrictions
>   when you configure bindings though.
>   The basic principle is that: the
>   settings for the WCF binding should be
>   compatible with IIS settings. This
>   means that if you want to enable
>   transport layer authentication in the
>   binding, you have to do so to the
>   virtual application in IIS. For
>   example, when you use
>   BasicHttpBinding, you can enable the
>   transport layer auth by setting the
>   security Mode to
>   "TransportCredentialOnly". You can
>   disable IIS anonymous auth in this
>   case.
>
> However, there is one special case: if
>   you are using WSHttpBinding over HTTP
>   instead of HTTPS, you would have to
>   enable anonymous in IIS. This is
>   because none of the security modes for
>   WSHttpBinding allows you to configure
>   transport-layer authentication over
>   HTTP, which has been implemented in
>   BasicHttpBinding. Of course, you can
>   solve this by using either
>   BasicHttpBinding or CustomBinding.
>   This is not a limitation. Instead it
>   tries to reduce confusion since you
>   would use either SSL (as transport
>   layer security) or message security
>   with WSHttpBinding.